# Why aren't Identity Cookies saved and sent back to BackEnd for authentication and authorization?

Tags: reactjs, http, cookies, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API backend and a React Js with Typescript and Vite for frontend.

I use Identity with Entity Framework Core for the user management part. The auth should be done by the cookies that are automatically set by Identity.

This is where I add Identity:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TenantDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

This is where I configure the Identity cookie:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Prevent redirect to login page
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };

    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };

    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; //this is important to be true
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; //this is important to be true

    // Configure other properties as needed
    options.LoginPath = "/api/your-login-path";
    options.LogoutPath = "/api/your-logout-path";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/api/access-denied-path";
});

services.AddAuthorization();
```

In my React frontend, I have a `BaseApiService` class with the following constructor:

```
export abstract class BaseApiService {
  protected readonly instance: AxiosInstance;
  protected readonly servicePath: string;

  protected constructor(
    baseURL: string,
    controllerName: string,
    tenantId: string
  ) {
    this.servicePath = `/${tenantId}/${controllerName}`;
    this.instance = axios.create({
      baseURL,
      withCredentials: true, //this one is important
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
    });
  }
```

And just to make sure, I also set `{ withCredentials: true }` in my serviceMethods.

When I call the `Login` endpoint, I can see in the response headers that `Set-Cookie` attributes does exist, like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3000
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 19 Feb 2024 16:10:11 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Kestrel
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=chunks-2;  path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.ApplicationC1=cookie_content; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.ApplicationC2=cookie_content2; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
```

My problem is that the cookies are not saved and consequently not sent back to the backend.

I have tried:

- any combination of configuration for the cookie
- use mkcert to get a ssl for 127.0.0.1 and localhost for the frontend and configured vite to serve over https

The same thing resulted, cookies were not saved, so they weren't sent to backend and the request resulted in 401 http code response.

Comment: make sure the certificate you have created is installed and trusted by the system. are you using https for both url? could you try setting samesite to SameSite=None; Secure.When setting a cookie with SameSite=None, the website must also include the Secure attribute, which ensures that the cookie is only sent in encrypted messages over HTTPS. Otherwise, browsers will reject the cookie and it won't be set. check the browser application tab and console it might give some insight if cookie is being rejected. could you share your backend code which you have set for cors?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out. This is kinda of a newbie error on my part, but it is what it is.

So, apart from the baseApiService class in Typescript, I had a different apiService class that handles accountController actions. On this particular apiService, that instantiated it's own axios object, I did not set the withCredentials: true, and because of that when receiving the cookies the browser would not set them.

Takeaway:

If you want the browser to **set the cookies received from Backend**, use withCredentials: true for the axios instance that receives (and by default makes) the login response.

If you want the browser to **send back to Backend those cookies**, set the withCredetials: true for the axios instance that makes the request.

Be cautious when using different axios (or whatever else) instances.

Sorry guys, and thank you!

See you around